# How to check if the value is existing in DB

Tags: database, go, go-gorm

How do I check if the value that I want to insert is existing in database or not

Let say I have

```
type studentRepository struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

type Student struct {
    Name string     `json:"name"`
    Age int         `json:"age"`
}

func(s student) CreateStudent(v Student) (*Student, error) {
    db := p.db.Create(&v)
    return &v, db.Error
}
```

I want to create new student but cannot have the same name with other students. How can I check if the name that I want to insert is not existing in the db?

```
Example: 
StudentList = {Messi, Ronaldo, Tevez}
WantToInsert = {Ronaldo}
Result = Cannot happened because Ronaldo is existing on the list
```

Comment: In general you just go ahead and try to insert, and handle the error if insertion fails due to duplication. You may execute a query to find out if such an entry already exists, but in general that's not a guarantee that insertion succeeds if not, as another process / instance running concurrently might create it first.

Comment: Which means I have to generate get function with param name and compare the value after I created student object?

Comment: You just insert. If an error occurs telling you that the key already exists, you know it was already there. If the name is not part of the primary key, create an additional `unique` index on the table.
Querying isn't reliable, as icza said. You might query with the result that the entry does not exist yet. You insert, but in the meantime another process has already written a studient with the same name into the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can prevent inputting the same value by creating "unique" constraint in your SQL database ,
Gorm allows that adding unique keyword to your struct:

```
type Student struct {
    Name string     `json:"name" gorm:"unique"`
    Age int         `json:"age"`
}
```

you can refer to Gorm's documentation for more details:
[Gorm indexing documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/indexes.html#Index-Tag)

you can also catch duplicate error for logging purposes
the implementation differs depending on the database you're using,
this example works in the case of using Postgresql:

```
err := db.Create(student).Error

if err != nil {
    var pgErr *pgconn.PgError
    if errors.As(err, &pgErr) && (pgErr.Code == "23505") {
        // handle error here
    }
}
```